# Eclipse - play/pause ... buttons enabled on startup

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon, eclipse-oxygen

I'm working with Eclipse Neon. I noticed that the some buttons in IDE are set enabled by default b startup and if I click them a message pops up saying **"The chosen operation is not enabled."** See the image attached.

[image: Enabled buttons and message on click]

Is it a bug in Eclipse IDE or am I missing something?

Comment: may i know java version you are using

Comment: @harshakumarReddy Its 1.8 update 131

Comment: Those operation are available only when you are running application in debug mode .Have some breakpoints in your application and  try running the application in debug mode and see if those options are available

Comment: @harshakumarReddy Its enabled when I **start up** the IDE, not switching the perspectives. I wonder why those buttons enabled at stratup. Is it some sort of UI bug in Eclipse?

Comment: I can observe the issue also in Eclipse Oxygen RC2.

Comment: Still present in version : 2018-09 (4.9.0)